# Angular2 Http POST request error

Tags: angular

I have written code for login service. Http post request is throwing 'Server error'. Server API is working fine, validated it with Postman. Below is the client side authentication(login) service script. Kindly help me where i went wrong.

**authentication.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticateService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        var url = 'http://localhost/project/api/authenticate';
        var data = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password});

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

        return this.http.post(url, data, options)
            .map((response:Response) => {
                // some code
            })
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error in the server?

Comment: No, request not coming to server. Catch operator is throwing error.

Comment: You not need  JSON.stringify, try put { username: username, password: password} only, and the url not need a port is only localhost?

Comment: its better to put your credentials encoded in the http header as follows.            let digest = btoa(`${username}:${password}`);
        myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + digest);

Comment: I have tried your suggestion @alehn96 it's not working. Ya port is not needed it-seems because same **URL** is working fine in **POSTMAN**.

Comment: In **catch** `console.log(JSON.stringify(error));` is printing _{"_body":{"isTrusted":true},"status":0,"ok":false,"statusText":"","headers":{},"type":3,"url":null}_

Comment: With Postam the service work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my issue. Included below code at client and server side script.

**Client:**

```
headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
```

**Server code:**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers');
```